# Can you call two different overloaded constructors from in the same instance of a class in java?

Tags: java, class, constructor, calculator

I am working on a simple calculator problem and i am making a class specifically to handle the operations. I am making two constructors within the class one taking one int and one taking two. What i plan to do is that when the user inputs the first number into the program, the first constructor will be called and the first number will be saved. When they enter the second number, the same instance of the class will be called but this time with both the variables in a constructor. Is this possible? Is there an easier way to do this? thanks.

Comment: You can't construct the same instance twice. So no.

Comment: You need to use regular functions.

Comment: could you please post code ?

Comment: i dont have any code yet i am still trying to plan it out

Comment: Why use constructors? Once you have an instance, your second case is about changing the state and could be done by setters. If this does not make sense, then perhaps what you really need is 2 instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize the same instance of a class multiple times.  What you can do, however, is change the value of any non-final instance or static variables in the class after you've called the constructor.  It's best coding practice to avoid adding any code except for initialization of instance variables to the constructors, and what you can do is move any code in question to other methods so you can call it where you were thinking of calling the constructor the 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not directly possible since a constructor can only be called upon class instantiation. You can use something like the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call another constructor within another overloaded constructor.

In your constructor, type `this(yourParameters)` and that calls the other constructor.

Example:

```
class Example 
{
    public Example()
    {
        this(1); // calls the other constructor
    }
    public Example(int par1)
    {
        // some code here
    } 
}
```

But other than that, you cannot call constructors explicitly like you can with methods.